# generate unique visitorId in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to generate visitorId in JS, max length is 7 chars, valid chars are [0-9][A-Z], any ideas?

Comment: So, after 36 mio. hits your page will break, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm almost certain that you can't do what you want in pure Javascript, because you can't co-ordinate between the different visitors.

With only 7 characters, the range of available values is relatively small - by which I mean, small enough that any pseudo-random assignment of values by the client will almost certainly result in a clash very quickly (see [Birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)).

If you try to work around it by, say, appending the time at which the visitor was first seen - this is a good strategy *in general*, but here it's eating even more into your entropy.  If you could encode this time in four characters, you've then got only 3 characters to differentiate between clients arriving during the same second (according to *their* clocks) and you're going to get a collision again.

Basically, this isn't going to be solvable without either:

- Some help from the server - i.e. the server embeds a seed number in the page, which **can** be assured to be unique because it's server-side, you can have the client JS transform this into an alphanumeric ID somehow.
- Making the character **much** bigger - if you can have 64 characters in the visitorID, for instance, you can encode the timestamp down to the millisecond, the visitor's IP address and possibly some other unique information, *and* then a random component.  The chance of clashes here would likely head towards the chance of an MD5 hash collision, i.e. the point at which it's acceptable.  (But *calculate* based on what you know about your visitors!)

Comment: what do you think about next: first 3 letters is current date and month, last 4 is random generated...

Comment: Andrew - that leaves only ~1.7m options (36^4) for the last 4 characters.  This gives a 10% chance of collision after 595 visitors on the same day/month, a 50% chance after 1526 visitors and a 90% chance after 2782.  That's really not good enough, and I don't think you *can* get "good enough" with only seven characters **and** no server-side coordination.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the "uniqueness" you want, and then you can do a md5 hash of the "key" values defining your user (for instance, IP)

Comment: This is a good point. The methods described earlier does not consider for uniqueness. Although very small in probability, same id maybe generated for different users.

Answer (score -1):

If you want just a random string, I found this function by googleing:

```
function randomString(string_length) {
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var randomstring = '';
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
    document.randform.randomfield.value = randomstring;
}
```

Comment: He did not specify any particular usage or context, thus a random alphanumeric string would serve as a perfect identifier (i.e. UUID). With regard to the small probability of generating the same ID, this could also happen with UUID, so to be sure you would run it in a while loop checking against existing IDs. This is a valid answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
function rand( min, max ) {
    if( max ) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    } else {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (min + 1));
    }
}

function getVisitorId() {
  var alpha = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  var id = '';
  for(var i=0;i<7i++) id+=alpha.charAt(rand(0,35));
  return id;
}
```